# Run Command after Laptop unfold

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I want to run a bash file at a specific moment a day. (8:00 and 20:00).

I've already managed to do this via crontab and also on startup if my computer was shut down at the time. My only problem is when my laptop is closed or locked (windows_key + L). Is there any way to run my file when I relogin to my computer or even when I unfold it? Because I don't want crontab to run every minute and then check in the bash file for the right time? I've already found various examples for the startup scenario but this doesn't cover the unfolding of the laptop and the lock screen.

Comment: [Run scripts for laptop lid open/close and dock/undock events](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1076486.html) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the scheduled task to be persistent regardless of shutdowns or suspends, then systemd timers might be a good fit.

There is a `Persistent=true` option for `systemd.timer`. It stores the last triggered time on disk. The next time the timer is activated (eg. autostart on startup or resume from sleep), it would check the stored time and determine whether to be triggered.

To use systemd timers, there are many good docs to read, but the TL;DR is:

1. You'll need two short systemd unit files, one `action.service`, containing the commands, and one `action.timer`, containing the scheduled time and persistence.
2. Then you want to enable and start `action.timer` by `systemctl enable action.timer` and `systemctl start action.timer`, for it to be effective.
3. Now when the time has come, `action.timer` would activate `action.service`.